# How to fix lags and more RAM consumption in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: ram, 19.04, memory-usage

I recently updated to Ubuntu 19.04 from 18.10.

In this version, RAM consumption is more than before. Also, my PC lags every time I open a new app. Sometimes many apps respond with a force quit option.

In 18.10 everything was working nicely with no more than 2 GB RAM consumption.

[image: Process & RAM Usage]

Comment: Put up a screenshot of the processes tab sorted by RAM.

Comment: Reboot. Then temporarily try `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80` and see if there's any improvement.